# Creating Bootstrap Table with PHP/Json Array?

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, datatables

So I'm trying to take json data such as show [image: Here --->]

```
{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":1,"identifiers":["license:LICENSEKEY","xbl:XBLKEY","live:LIVEKEY","discord:DISCORDID","fivem:FIVEMKEY","license2:LICENSE2KEY"],"name":"Username","ping":54}]
```

And result the display in a bootstrap table such as this [image: Here --->]

**
This is how I've currently gotten the table setup**

```
  <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>    ID</th>
                                    <th>    Player Name</th>
                                    <th>    License (Rockstar License)</th>
                                    <th>    Discord ID</th>
                                    <th>    Steam Identifier</th>
                                    <th>    Ping</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <?php foreach ($json as $player){ ?>
        <td> <?php echo $player['id']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $player['name']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $player['license']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $player['discord']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $player['steam']; ?> </td>
        <td> <span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger"><?php echo $player['ping']; ?> </span></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
                        </table>
```

As you can see the error I'm coming across is getting the License/Discord/Steam Identifier to actually post back to the table, I'm sure it's a loop array but I'm not quite just sure how... I can go about getting it done.

Comment: Your JSON up there is hardly readable. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Like the above error message, you are trying to access keys that do not exist, I realized that those keys are in an array that is the value of key "identifiers". You need to loop over the array of this key